# A good way to organize/store a lot of datasets

Tags: dataset, machine-translation, best-practice

In machine translation, we often have bilingual dataset, e.g. for German-English and French-English we will have something that looks like this:

```
/en-de
   train.de
   train.en
   dev.de
   dev.en
   test.de
   test.en

/en-fr
   train.fr
   train.en
   dev.fr
   dev.en
   test.fr
   test.en
```

And then we have a third language pair German-French, and we'll have:

```
/de-fr
   train.fr
   train.de
   dev.fr
   dev.de
   test.fr
   test.de
```

But lets say we add Spanish-English and we'll get:

```
/en-es
   train.es
   train.en
   dev.es
   dev.en
   test.es
   test.en

/de-es
   train.es
   train.de
   dev.es
   dev.de
   test.es
   test.de

/fr-es
   train.es
   train.fr
   dev.es
   dev.fr
   test.es
   test.fr
```

And if we add even more languages, these pairs of languages goes even more tedious.

**What would be a good data structure / directory organization to store the `train.*`, `dev.*` and `test.*` files?**

Answer (score 3):

At this scale, `grep` is fast enough, so it's just a matter of having the files in a shape that's convenient for the most common types of searches.

At ModelFront, we use and recommend **Linear TSV**, because TSV has first-class support in bash.

https://modelfront.com/docs/eval/#linear-tsv explains the standard and why it's such a natural fit for machine translation data:

> For natural language text data, especially parallel data, TSV has key advantages over CSV and XML.
>
> ###### Human-readability
>
> ...
>
> ###### Standardization
>
> ...
>
> ###### Scalability
>
> ModelFront is built to handle very large files. TSV can be read in line by line - without reading the whole file into memory.
> TSV is also more compact than CSV or XML.
>
> ###### Convenience
>
> The built-in command-line tools like `cut` and `paste` read and write TSV by default and fundamentally operate at the line level.

So we do not split sentence pairs (or their metadata) across multiple aligned files - that's unwieldy and asking for trouble.

But we only have one language pair and dataset per file - and we note those in the file name - instead of using an additional column, because usually that's the level at which you want to search.

And it's always possible to do multiple searches, `find` or `cat` if you want to search across language pairs and datasets.

(And we obviously don't use XML, and we are disappointed that WMT chose not just XML but yet another non-standardised XML format.)

So your example would end up something like this:

```
en.de.train.tsv
en.de.dev.tsv
en.de.test.tsv
en.fr.train.tsv
...
```

Comment: No, it's not a project, it's an API and console for using the API and for training, testing, deploying translation risk prediction models to the API.  It hosts open datasets openly at https://console.modelfront.com/#/explore, so if you have access to a Unix terminal with the right flavour of bash, you can try out the *Filtering*, *Sorting*, *Slicing* and *Joining* documented at https://modelfront.com/docs/eval/#downloading on those open datasets.

Answer (score 1):

File systems are good enough for data storage up to a point. As data becomes more complex, it often makes sense to move to a database.

A relationship database will allow for database normalization, storing a single, canonical value for each entity. This will greatly reduce the size of the data and allow for different combinations of train, dev, and test datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Data structures for multi-lingual can be bit tiresome & repetitive, especially if data is not structured properly.

Assuming the content of data in `en` is the same across in other languages `en-es`, `en-fr`, `en-de`. In other words, `train.en` is same in `en-es`, `en-fr` and `en-de`

considering word hello:

- English(en) its Hello
- Spanish(es) its Hola
- French(fr) its Bonjour
- German(de) its Guten tag

This Data structure is most simplest across different environments **`train.*` , `dev.*` , `test.*`**  which can accommodate other new language translations

```
     /train
       en
       es
       fr
       de

      /dev
       en
       es
       fr
       de

     /test
       en
       es
       fr
       de
```

New translation chinese to spanish `cn-es` would be simplified by just adding the chinese translation in this data structure.

```
     \train
       en
       es
       fr
       de
       cn
```